# Woocommerce solicita el email a pesar de que ya está relleno

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Mis clientes no pueden completar sus pedidos descargables realizados a través de WooCommerce. El sistema está solicitando una dirección de correo electrónico a pesar de que ya está rellenada. Como puedo arreglarlo?

[Mensaje de error: Por favor, rellene el email](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DnmOR.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por favor, comprueba que las características de ese producto en particular, tal vez solo hayas la opción "descargable" cuando también debería ser "virtual". Simplemente actívalo y listo.

Fuente: https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-order-status-control/